# How to typeset a "compact" cases environment

Tags: align, cases

What's the proper way to typeset a `cases` environment in a compact way?

I tried the following:

```
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\lambda = 
\tiny \begin{cases}
 -8.30767 x^3+702.515 x^2-1905.35 x+1307.96 & 0.\leq r<1221.5 \\
 \begin{aligned}
 & -1018.45 x^9+49.589 x^8-491.158 x^7+3871.91 x^6-1250.75 x^5 \\
 & +2143.9 x^4-4765.99 x^3+1208.14 x^2-1276.41 x+1535.87
 \end{aligned} & 1221.5<r<3480. \\
 \begin{aligned}
 & -14.1574 x^9+85.7979 x^8-267.899 x^7+861.531 x^6-2011.89 x^5 \\
 & +3277.38 x^4-4345.17 x^3+4064.09 x^2-2538.21 x+1121.09
 \end{aligned} & 3480.<r<3630. \\
 \begin{aligned}
 & -1656.31 x^9+9271.49 x^8-25812.7 x^7+49845.7 x^6-71507.8 x^5\\
 & +76291.1 x^4-61014.1 x^3+35291.1 x^2-13586.7 x+2969.32
 \end{aligned} & 3630.<r<5600. \\
 \begin{aligned}
 & -14.1574 x^9+85.7979 x^8-780.947 x^7+3240.92 x^6-6331. x^5\\
 & +7802.27 x^4-6886.25 x^3+1978.92 x^2+2186.71 x-1126.32
 \end{aligned} & 5600.<r<5701. \\
 -72.258 x^3+525.939 x^2-1202.04 x+879.289 & 5701.<r<5771. \\
 -2995.06 x^3+11650. x^2-15077.1 x+6492.61 & 5771.<r<5971. \\
 -420.221 x^3+2079.69 x^2-3391.49 x+1817.51 & 5971.<r<6151. \\
 3.10353 x^3+20.9044 x^2+40.0953 x+22.2648 & 6151.<r<6346.6 \\
 45.878 & 6346.6<r<6356. \\
 34.216 & 6356.<r<6368. \\
 2.14455 & 6368.<r\leq 6371. \\
\end{cases} 
\text{,}
\end{equation*}
```

but:

- `\tiny` raise a warning ("Command \tiny invalid in math mode")
- general appearance is not satisfactoing (the cases on two lines are difficult to relate to the conditions)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tough display! I'd avoid `\tiny`, not only because of the warning, but rescale the body of the `cases` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{array}

\NewEnviron{breakcase}{%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
  \begin{array}{@{\hspace{2em}}>{{}}l@{}}
  \hspace{-2em}\mathopen{}\BODY
  \end{array}%
}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\lambda = \left\{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\resizebox{.8\textwidth}{!}{%
 \setlength{\jot}{-2pt}%
 $\begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l}
 -8.30767 x^3+702.515 x^2-1905.35 x+1307.96 & 0.\leq r<1221.5 \\
 \begin{breakcase}
  -1018.45 x^9+49.589 x^8-491.158 x^7+3871.91 x^6-1250.75 x^5 \\
  +2143.9 x^4-4765.99 x^3+1208.14 x^2-1276.41 x+1535.87
 \end{breakcase} & 1221.5<r<3480. \\
 \begin{breakcase}
  -14.1574 x^9+85.7979 x^8-267.899 x^7+861.531 x^6-2011.89 x^5 \\
  +3277.38 x^4-4345.17 x^3+4064.09 x^2-2538.21 x+1121.09
 \end{breakcase} & 3480.<r<3630. \\
 \begin{breakcase}
  -1656.31 x^9+9271.49 x^8-25812.7 x^7+49845.7 x^6-71507.8 x^5\\
  +76291.1 x^4-61014.1 x^3+35291.1 x^2-13586.7 x+2969.32
 \end{breakcase} & 3630.<r<5600. \\
 \begin{breakcase}
  -14.1574 x^9+85.7979 x^8-780.947 x^7+3240.92 x^6-6331. x^5\\
  +7802.27 x^4-6886.25 x^3+1978.92 x^2+2186.71 x-1126.32
 \end{breakcase} & 5600.<r<5701. \\
 -72.258 x^3+525.939 x^2-1202.04 x+879.289 & 5701.<r<5771. \\
 -2995.06 x^3+11650. x^2-15077.1 x+6492.61 & 5771.<r<5971. \\
 -420.221 x^3+2079.69 x^2-3391.49 x+1817.51 & 5971.<r<6151. \\
 3.10353 x^3+20.9044 x^2+40.0953 x+22.2648 & 6151.<r<6346.6 \\
 45.878 & 6346.6<r<6356. \\
 34.216 & 6356.<r<6368. \\
 2.14455 & 6368.<r\leq 6371.
\end{array}$}
\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

For the broken lines, I used some trickery for getting a more sensible alignment that better shows the breaks.

I removed the trailing comma that, though grammatically correct, would appear as hanging from nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is more or less what I was trying to get without success. Instead of `breakcase` environment it is not possible to use some common construct like `multiline` `split` `align`...?

Comment: @unlikely Possibly, but I saw they used much wider interline space.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are trying to give the reader a certain amount of data. If you don't, you could get rid of some digits after the comma or replace some rows by ellipses...

As all this information seems to be important for the reader, you should clearly help to read that information. An equation like yours is more a "let's see if next page is easier..." kind of information.

I would propose to put everything in a table which is the standard format for such thing. Here is some example. Please understand that I did not want to type the whole thing.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
The variable $\lambda$ can be described by the formula
\[\lambda=A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3+Ex^4+Fx^5+Gx^6+Hx^7+Ix^8+Kx^9\]
in which the coefficients depend on the range of $r$.  Coefficients and coresponding ranges are shown in table \ref{tab:lambda}.
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Parameters for the $\lambda$-formula}\label{tab:lambda}
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1.1mm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=-4.5]SSSSSSSSS>{$}l<{$}@{}}
        \toprule
        {$A$} & {$B$} & {$C$} & {$D$} & {$E$} & $F$ & $G$ & $H$ & $I$ & $K$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$}\\
        \midrule
        1307.96 & -1905.35 & 702.515 & -8.30767 &&&&&&& [0,12521.5)\\
        1535.87 & -1276.41 & 1208.14 & -4765.99 & 2143.9 & -1250.75 & 3871.91 & -491.158 & 49.589 & -1018.45 & (1221.5,3480)\\
        1121.09 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        2969.32 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        -1126.32 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        879.289 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        6492.61 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        1817.51 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        22.2648 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        45.878 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (6346.6,6356) \\
        34.216 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (6356,6368) \\
        2.14455 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (6368,6371] \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to compile your code because of some missing/not-up-to-date package, but I already tried by myself to put these data on a table. But, because I have 5-6 of these expressions, each with up to 8 branches, and each branch with up to 9 coefficient, I think the end result is a bit distracting. I think the formula is easy to understand and, when necessary, to read.